# Similarity transformation-proof of equivalence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, transformation, equivalence-relations

I am getting stuck with following problem:

Show that
\begin{align}
\dot{x} = f(x/t)
\end{align}
is equivalent to
\begin{align}
\dot{y} = (f(y) − y)/t
\end{align}
using the transformation 
\begin{align}
y := x/t.
\end{align}

Any help/hint is welcomed.

Comment: If you want to put a dot over the $x$, use the code `\dot{x}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y=\frac{x}{t}$, we have 
$$\begin{align}
\dot{y} &= \frac{\dot{x}t-x}{t^{2}} \tag{derivative of a quotient}\\
&= \frac{f\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)t-x}{t^{2}} \tag{$\dot{x}=f(x/t)$}\\
&= \frac{f\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)t}{t^{2}}-\frac{x}{t}\cdot\frac{1}{t}\\
&= \frac{f(y)}{t} - y\cdot\frac{1}{t} \tag{since $t\neq 0$}\\
&= \frac{f(y)-y}{t}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

sometimes a small transformation of a problem makes it easier to approach. here you may write the transformation as $yt=x$. then, differentiating wrt t we get (using the product rule)
$$
y+t\dot{y}=\dot{x}=f(y)
$$
and the required answer is obtained by a simple algebraic manipulation